# Unity Question dealing with Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The ring $\{0, 2 ,4, 6, 8\}$ under addition and multiplication modulo $10$ has a unity. Find it.
Is the unity because this is only a set of evens?

I don't really understand unity. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Unity in a commutative ring $R$ is an element $u\in R$ such that for every $r\in R$ we have $ur=r$. The simplest way to find it is to just check each element and see if it satisfies this condition.

To simplify calculations, first find $u$ such that $u\cdot 2=2$ (multiplying by two is easy, multiplying by eight isn't *that* hard, but not all that easy) and then check that it is indeed the unity (or, if you want to be smart, you can just notice that if $u\cdot 2=2$ then $u$ is automatically the unity since $2$ generates the ring, additively, and multiplication is distributive).

Comment: Thank you.  That helps a lot